# RectilinearGridSource from tvtk.RectilinearGrid()

Tags: python, mayavi

I am trying to construct `tvtk.RectilinearGridSource` from `tvtk.RectilinearGrid` object in order to add it to the `mayavi.engine`.

I used to do this:

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

r = tvtk.RectilinearGrid()
r.point_data.scalars = data.ravel()
r.point_data.scalars.name = 'Temperature'

d = mlab.pipline.add_dataset(r)
```

but instead I would prefer to call it this way:

```
from mayavi.api import Engine
e = Engine()
e.start()
s = e.new_scene()
src = tvtk.RectilinearGridSource()
```

and then link `src` with `r` i.e., with my `RectilinearGrid` defined before.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer:

```
r = tvtk.RectilinearGrid()
r.point_data.scalars = data.ravel()
r.point_data.scalars.name = 'Temperature'

from mayavi.sources.vtk_data_source import VTKDataSource
src = VTKDataSource(data=r)

e.add_source(d)
```